# Element-wise multiplication between dataframe and array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas dataframe "A":

```
    0   1   2
0  10   5   7
1   5  20  14
2   7  14  30
```

and the following numpy array "B":

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

I want to perform an element-wise multiplication between "A" and "B":

```
C = A*B
```

results in

```
    0   1   2
0  10  10  21
1   5  40  42
2   7  28  90
```

Now I want to perform an element-wise multiplication between "C" and transposed (vertical) "B".
I tried:

```
D = C * B.T
```

and

```
D = np.multiply(C,np.transpose(B))
```

but both result in:

```
    0   1    2
0  10  20   63
1   5  80  126
2   7  56  270
```

instead of the expected

```
    0   1    2
0  10  10   21
1  10  80   84
2  21  84  270
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `C.mul(B, 0)` or `C * B.reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: you forgot to examine `B.T` or read `np.transpose` docs.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny 's  solutions both worked fine